# when to use ".copy()" and "=" in lists in python. Is there any differneces

Tags: python

in lists there is this feature called ".copy()". However I am a bit confuse whether to use ".copy()" over "=" and vice versa since both act exactly the same. Here is an example:

```
friends = ["Tom", "holland", "Steves", "Jim", "Jimmy", "Boy"]
friends2 = friends.copy()
print(friends2)
print(friends)
```

and the result obtain is this:

```
['Tom', 'holland', 'Steves', 'Jim', 'Jimmy', 'Boy']
['Tom', 'holland', 'Steves', 'Jim', 'Jimmy', 'Boy']
```

and if you use "=" instead of ".copy()", you get the same result. Example:

```
friends = ["Tom", "holland", "Steves", "Jim", "Jimmy", "Boy"]
friends2 = friends
print(friends2)
print(friends)
```

you get the same result.

So is there any differences in the both keyword. If there is which one should I use in different situations.

Comment: You will notice the difference if you try appending or changing something in `friends`. With `=` you only have one list in memory. Changes will be reflected in both `friends` and `freinds2` since they are the same list.

Comment: just update a value in list in both case and print, you will find the difference, value in both list will be remain same in `=` case and `copy` case it will change only in 1 case

Comment: just update a value in one list in both case and print, you will find the difference, value in both list will be remain same in `=` case and `copy` case it will change only in 1 case

Comment: It is true but why is that so

Comment: For example if you change in friends2 and did not change in friends, why does friends also change

Comment: Because when you say `a = b`, you are NOT making another copy of b; you are just assigning `a` as another _name_ for `b`.